# html input type datetime-local to datetime sql using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have this object created in my web page.

input type="datetime-local" name="datentime" size="15" style="height:30px; font-size:18px" placeholder="

Now I need to retrieve the value and put it into my mysql database. I tried a lot but couldn't insert value to database. my php code is given below.

```
$event_dnt = strtotime($_POST["datentime"]);
```

database store as YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

Comment: The code you show won't insert anything into a table. It's just assigning a value to a variable. Show your code, and show the table schema.

Answer (score 2):

Convert date from `dd/mm/yyyy h:i` (Default for input type datetime-local format) to `Y-m-d H:i:s` (Mysql format) to save in database, use code following:

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($_POST["datentime"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You must convert timestamp time (which return strtotime function) to database format string.

For example,

```
$_POST["datentime"] = '20.06.2018 10:12:45'; # OR '2018-06-08 10:12:45' -- just input sumulation
$data = $_POST["datentime"];
$dbInsertDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($data));
```

In addition, check $_POST["datentime"] for needed format by regexp.